# Maintaining absolute references when adding new rows to a sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

When I add a new row for the current reporting month to the top (becomes row 9), my absolute cell references in my formulas on rows 3–5 change to move down a row, now referencing rows 10 and 11, instead of rows 9 and 10. Which I'm sure is intended behaviour for the spreadsheet.

However I always want the data in rows 9 and 10 to be compared (the most current two months).

Eg at the end of August I will add a new row 9 for August 2020, and I want to compare August with July, not continue to compare July with June. Seems intuitive / straightforward enough, but somehow need to work around how Google Sheets treats these references.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to **{Stephen,G}** for this [simple answer](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/63272194?hl=en&msgid=63274066#) on the Google Docs Editors Community.

The `INDIRECT` function was what I needed. I had tried it myself previously but I made the simple error of not wrapping the cell reference in double quotes (not sure why that is exactly, but that's how it goes!)

Eg `INDIRECT("$B$9")`

Comment: Hopefully that helps some others.